# Array of last week dates (starting for latest monday)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I have to generate a report, which will consist data for last week starting from monday (if today is monday, then only display the today's date and count).
Can I know how can I get the last week dates array(starting from last monday)?
Thanks.

I wrote this, but in this case if last week start date is 31, then the next day becomes 32, which is not possible.

```
$last_week_date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last monday')) + 1;
```

I want a array of dates.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add inside +1

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $last_week_dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last monday + '.$i.' day'));
}

/*
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-20"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-21"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-22"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-23"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-24"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-25"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2012-08-26"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over all of the days in the report, you can do this:

```
for ($date = strtotime('last monday'); $date < time(); $date += 24*60*60) {
  // e.g. date('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

However, to fetch the data from the database you could do:

```sql
SELECT   DATE(date), COUNT(*)
FROM     my_table
WHERE    DATE(date) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
                        AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use SQL to do all the work for you? If you are pulling data from mysql (as your question tags might suggest) you can use the following nicely:

```
select date_sub(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'), interval WEEKDAY(now()) day) as date from dual;
```

This gives you the date of Last Monday:

```
mysql> select date_sub(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'), interval WEEKDAY(now()) day) as date from dual;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2012-08-27 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If it is Monday, it uses the current week of information. You can modify it a touch to suit your needs though.

Comment: NB: there won't be any record in the resultset for dates for which there is no data in the database -- one may still wish to display such dates in the report, in which case a loop in PHP (that compares each report date with that of the next record in your resultset ordered by date) is probably best option.

Comment: @eggyal Yes, I agree, but when I answered, all the answers pointed to a pure PHP solution. I thought I would add in other options.